# How to update nodejs version on amazon lightsail server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-lightsail

I just blindly updated the npm version on my amazon lightsail instance and now npm is not working because nodejs v12 does not support the safe-dot reference.

I just followed their "advice" here at https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/upgrade-npm/

I am not very clever so I cannot figure out how to update nodejs without npm. Nodejs or npm are NOT packages on the instance so `sudo apt-get` does not update or remove them. I don't even know where to look for the packages honestly. If someone can help me it would be appreciated.

- 2020 Amazon lightsail Nodejs environment.
- Node version v12.16.1
- npm 9.6.2

The error is obviously that I installed an npm version that does not support older nodejs version prior to v14. I am in a deadlock now because of that. I cannot use the npm command at all and I don't know where to remove this new npm version without using npm or system packages.

```
ERROR:
/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:21
  const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at module.exports (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:81:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
```

Comment: I did this in my AWS Lightsail instance few days back. I have documented the steps with screenshots here - https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/upgrade-nodejs-in-aws-lightsail/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out where nodejs and npm is installed with

```
which node
which npm
```

Then I went to nodejs website and downloaded the linux x64 pre-installed binaries for that node version, in my case under https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/.

From there I jsut copied the `npm` folder into the correct folder on the lightsail instance and it is working now again.

So if I wanna update my nodejs I will just decompress the tar-zipped binaries and install it into the `opt/bitnami` folder with the correct path on my instance